# What do "AFS" and "LTAFYDYX" mean according to the image in the LTAF AIP document?

Tags: general-aviation, airport, aeronautical-information

What do "AFS" and "LTAFYDYX" mean according to the image in the LTAF AIP document? I found that AFS stands for Aeronautical Fixed Service, but I don't know what it does and the meaning of the "LTAFYDYX" code in its description. (The texts I marked with yellow color in the image.)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFS is indeed an [Aeronatical Fixed Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_fixed_service)

It appears that LTAFYDYX us a skype ID according to this [courier tracking website](https://www.courierstracking.com/adana-sakirpasa-airport-customer-care-contact-address/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very weird and interesting to have a Skype ID belonging to an airport. I will accept your answer in 6 hours.

Comment: DHMI may reuse its AFS ID for its Skype account, but there is no link between AFS and Skype. The most probable is the site made an error replacing AFS by Skype.